# KDE shared desktop is graphically slanted

Tags: fedora, vnc, kde

Connecting from a Fedora 15 machine to a Fedora 15 machine, both running KDE, the remote machine running `krfb` and running `krdc` on the local machine, I connect to the remote machine over an ssh tunnel for port 5900.  The remote user is prompted to allow access, then I am prompted to enter a password, and then I see their desktop... but with a slant.

Essentially, the desktop appears as if the width is off by one or something.

What may be wrong here?  How can I get the desktop to display correctly?

**Edit:**  Changing the connection from 'low bandwidth' to 'medium bandwidth' corrected the problem.  So the question becomes "How can I get the desktop to display correctly with the low-bandwidth setting?"

Comment: Can you include a picture (perhaps from a digital camera?) of what you mean by "with a slant"?

Comment: Try an alternative VNC implementation. Install `x11vnc` on the remote machine, then [tunnel](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/#tunnelling) into it. For me, KRDC works fine at any resolution and colour depth.